# Annotation to make Jackson interpret field either as JSON array or JSON object

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have this model:

```
class Platform {
   private List<ACL> acl;
}
```

Whereas the source from the server can be

```
{ "acl" : [{ "id" : 1 }, { "id" : 2 }] }
```

or just a single Object

```
{ "acl" : "{ "id" : 1 } }
```

Is there a way to program Jackson to interpret field either as JSON array or JSON object?